# Thoughts leading to Curses

Tags: curse

So I've been thinking about curses could be passed? Many rishis cursed by holding some water in their hands and then utter their curse after which the water must be flung so that the curse is considered complete. I understand that, but can curses be transmitted using just our thoughts? No water, just negative thoughts about cursing a person while looking at them?

I'm intrigued by this question and would appreciate it if someone clarified this. Thank you!